# Unable to source in .screenrc

Tags: sh, screenrc

I have the following in my .screenrc

```
 source ~/bin/Screen/multiUserSettings
```

It gives me

```
No such file or directory
```

although I have it.

The following code says me that unknown command ".".

```
. ~/bin/Screen/multiUserSettings
```

It is strange, since I can source by . in .vimrc and .zshrc, for instance.

The file **multiUserSettings**

```
 # allow the following people full control
 addacl root,aledesma,mymanager,mycoworker1,mycoworker2
 aclchg aledesma +rwx ?#??

 # allow everyone readonly access
 aclchg *,!aledesma -rwx ?#??

 # setup 10,000 lines of available scrollback ? copy/paste
 defscrollback 10000

 # fix scrollback in putty
 termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

**How can you source in .screenrc?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
source /home/yourname/bin/Screen/multiUserSettings
```

instead. My guess is that screen does not support expanding ~ in that context.

If that does not work I think you should investigate to find out exactly which file name it complains "No such file or directory" about. You can use strace to log system calls for this.

Answer (score 11):

using an absolute path is not portable across machines (for instance, if you use git or svn to sync your .rc files across servers you log into).  Much better is to use the $HOME variable, which works in a .screenrc file.  E.g.:

```
source $HOME/bin/Screen/multiUserSettings
```

This way, if one machine on which you use your .screenrc has a home directory of /home/yourname, and another has /Users/yourname, and another has /opt/export/yourname, it'll all still just work.